# PHP: How can I have an array with same keys?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key, associative-array

I have 2 arrays `$projectsIds = [1,2]` and `$usersIds = [1,2,3]`

I have nasted foreach loop like this:

```
foreach($projectsIds as $projecID){
           foreach($userIds as $userID){
           $sync_array[$projecID] = array('user_id' => $userID);
            }
       }
dd($sync_array);
```

now I get result like this:

```
array:2 [  1 => array:1 [    "user_id" => 1  ]  
           2 => array:1 [    "user_id" => 1  ]
        ]
```

Is possible to get result something like this:

```
array:2 [  1 => array:1 [    "user_id" => 1  ]  
           1 => array:1 [    "user_id" => 2  ] 
           1 => array:1 [    "user_id" => 3  ]
           2 => array:1 [    "user_id" => 1  ]
           2 => array:1 [    "user_id" => 2  ]
           2 => array:1 [    "user_id" => 3  ]
        ]
```

Comment: `$sync_array[$projecID][] = array('user_id' => $userID);`?

Comment: Array keys are unique. So if you request your array e.g. `$ar[1]` -what should be returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wish to make an [array in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) having two or more of instances of the same key, which is not possible at all!

#### Keys are meant to be treated as unique entities